# git command is not recognized on Terminal tool window in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am trying to use Bitbucket with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

1. I went to *File >> Settings... >> Plugins* and installed the *Bitbucket* plugin. The *Git Integration* plugin seems enabled already.
2. I went to *File >> Settings... >> Other Settings >> Bitbucket* and logged in.
3. I installed *Git-1.9.5-preview20141217*.
4. I went to *File >> Settings... >> Version Control >> Git* and set *Path to Git executable* to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe*. Testing will find it.
5. I activated all this under *VCS*. I saw a successful message.

Then I created a repository on a team.
Now I must do the first commit, right?

> Already have a Git repository on your computer? Let's push it up to Bitbucket.

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/repo/s.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

I opened *View >> Tool Windows >> Terminal*.

> "git" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Since you've installed the BitBucket plugin, you don't need to use the terminal at all. Just invoke the "Share on BitBucket" action from the VCS menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The terminal tool window is just a terminal emulator for a command shell. In case of Windows that shell defaults to cmd, which is completely independent of the IDE settings. So in order for that to work you must have git in `PATH` environment variable.

You can do it this way:

1. Go to *Control panel/System/Advanced System Settings*
2. Click *Environment variables*
3. Select *PATH* and click *Edit*
4. Append following string at the end of the variable value: `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`

   - The semicolon is important, because individual PATH entries are delimited by it
   - The path to git bin directory might be different on your system

This works on Windows 8.1. It might be a little different on older versions of Window. Just in case here is a [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) which covers this procedure on more Windows versions.

Or you could set Git Bash as the shell for the Terminal tool window. Personally I prefer this approach on Windows computers. You can do it by going into *Settings/Terminal* and setting *Shell path* to something like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` (this might be different on your computer).

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but if your operating system is Windows 7 or later, you have the option to permanently add a path to the PATH environment variable using the elevated command prompt as well with the `setx` command:

`setx /M path "%path%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin"`

Note: path to the Git bin directory may vary on your system.